# Hide content after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have three drop down list and few text input,the first drop down is using to hide some input there are no need to show and the second drop down is using to reload the page and make the third drop down take the info from database base on the option in second drop down.Now I face a problem with when I click the second drop down,the page reload,and the input hide in drop down 1 show again....

code to get value after reload:

```
<?php
@$utm=$_GET['utm']; // Use this line or below line if register_global is off
if(strlen($utm) > 0 and !is_numeric($utm))
{ // to check if $utm is numeric data or not. 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
@$gpotp=$_GET['gpotp']; 
if(strlen($gpotp) > 0 and !is_numeric($gpotp))
{ 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
?>
```

javascript to hide content(call by drop down 1):

```
<script>
    function jsFunction(value)
{
var p = document.getElementById('ps');
var r = document.getElementById('rps');
var u = document.getElementById('upoint');
var m = document.getElementById('umng');
var t = document.getElementById('tmpass');
if ((value) == '1')
{
    p.style.display = '';
    r.style.display = '';
    u.style.display = 'none';
    m.style.display = 'none';
    t.style.display = 'none';
} 
else if ((value) == '2')
{
    p.style.display = 'none';
    r.style.display = 'none';
    u.style.display = '';
    m.style.display = 'none';
    t.style.display = '';
} 
if ((value) == '3')
{
    p.style.display = 'none';
    r.style.display = 'none';
    u.style.display = '';
    m.style.display = '';
    t.style.display = '';
} 

}
</script>
```

code to reload page(call when drop down 2):

```
function reload(form)
{

var val=form.utm.options[form.utm.options.selectedIndex].value;
var va2=form.gpotp.options[form.gpotp.options.selectedIndex].value;
self.location='CrtGroup.php?utm=' + val +'&gpotp=' + va2 ;

}
```

drop down 1:

```
<select name='gpotp' class='form-control' onmousedown=\"this.value='';\"  onchange=\"jsFunction(this.value);\">
                      <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>";
                      if($stmt = $conn->query("$query3"))
                        {
                            while ($row2 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                            if($row2['Group_ID']==@$gpotp){echo "<option selected value='$row2[Group_ID]'>$row2[Group_Cat]</option>";}
                        else{echo  "<option value='$row2[Group_ID]'>$row2[Group_Cat]</option>";}
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                        echo $conn->error;
                        }
    echo"</select>
```

drop down 2:

```
echo"<select class='form-control'  onchange=\"reload(this.form)\" name='utm' onmousedown=\"this.value='';\">";
                      echo"<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>";

                        if($stmt = $conn->query("$query2"))
                        {
                            while ($row2 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                            if($row2['Group_ID']==@$utm){echo "<option selected value='$row2[Group_ID]'>$row2[Tm_GroupID]</option>";}
                        else{echo  "<option value='$row2[Group_ID]'>$row2[Tm_GroupID]</option>";}
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                        echo $conn->error;
                        }

        echo"</select>";
```

drop down 3:

```
 echo"<select class='form-control' name='umn' >";
                      echo"<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>";

                        if(isset($utm) and strlen($utm) > 0){
                        if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Mng_GroupID,Group_ID,Tm_GroupID FROM mnggroup where Tm_GroupID=? order by Mng_GroupID"))
                        {
                        $stmt->bind_param('i',$utm);
                        $stmt->execute();
                         $result = $stmt->get_result();
                         while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          echo  "<option value='$row1[Group_ID]'>$row1[Mng_GroupID]</option>";
                            }

                        }else{
                         echo $conn->error;
                        } 

                        /////////
                        }else{
                        ///////
                        $query="SELECT DISTINCT Mng_GroupID,Group_ID,Tm_GroupID FROM mnggroup order by Mng_GroupID"; 

                        if($stmt = $conn->query("$query")){
                            while ($row1 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {

                        echo  "<option value='$row1[Group_ID]'>$row1[Mng_GroupID]</option>";

                          }
                        }else{
                        echo $conn->error;
                        }

                        } 

                   echo"</select>";
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code.

Comment: You would need to keep track with local-storage or cookies.

Comment: @DanPhilip Now my question is really relevant with this all code i post.Because each part of it might be affect the other code

Comment: @user7790438 Im sorry, I just new to programming can you explain more about keep track with local-storage or cookies how to solve this problem?

Comment: you dont need to reload the whole page. just reload the relevant dropdownlist

Comment: @Mark How to do that?Now I only know can reload the relevant dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.name to store a flag that persists after the reload.

No links, excuse me, but you could use it instead of local-storage or cookies for simply implementing a logic to hide what you want after the page reloading. Es.:

```
if (window.name === "hide") {
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: how to use window.name?have any example link?